# Mongoose multiple expression failed

Tags: mongodb, mongoose

```
module.exports.getApprovedPhotos = function(username,callback){
    Photos.find({username:username,approved:1}).sort({'_id':1}).exec(callback);
}
```

This will get the data from username with approved value equal to 1. But I'm getting approved value which are 0 too, how come?

Not sure it's a bug or something, any clue?

My schema

```
var photosSchema = mongoose.Schema({
    username:{
        type: String
    },
    photo: {
        type: String
    },
    caption: {
        type: String
    },
    approved: {
        type: Number,
        default: 0
    }
});
```

Comment: can you show structure of your document ?

Comment: This question has a duplicate. Awaiting moderation to close. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39683097/mongoose-multiple-expression-bug