# Mongoose multiple expression bug?

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, mongoose

I have my model like this

```
var photosSchema = mongoose.Schema({
    username:{
        type: String
    },
    photo: {
        type: String
    },
    caption: {
        type: String
    },
    approved: {
        type: Number,
        default: 0
    }
});

var Photos = module.exports = mongoose.model('photos', photosSchema);

module.exports.getApprovedPhotos = function(username,callback){
Photos.find({username:username,approved:1}).sort({'_id':1}).exec(callback);
```

}

I want to get approved photo. I test it with POSTMAN

[image]

As you can see I have 2 object which its approved is 0, how come it can be appear in my fetch? Is this a bug in mongoose? or there's a problem in my query?

Comment: Also note that the better way to attach methods to the schema is through "statics": http://mongoosejs.com/docs/guide.html#statics

Comment: @JoeFrambach I just want to know why it doesn't work as expected, I've been using mongoose back then and it was fine.

Comment: Could not reproduce the issue: http://pastebin.com/LNFktMvA

Comment: @JoeFrambach I used the wrong method LOL!

Answer (score 1):

As I seeing you are not doing any `query` for `approved`. You are just giving query to get all items which belong that `username`.

You need to also give as `query` for `approved` property 
Try this

```
 module.exports.getPhotosById = function(username,callback){
        Photos.find({username:username,approved:1}).sort({'_id':1}).exec(callback);
    }
```

Comment: mean still you are getting `approved: 0` values?

Comment: obviously. Look at the response in my POSTMAN

Comment: Did you try same query with mongo console?

Comment: I used the wrong method, solved, not a bug, it's my mistake lol!